# Revert ProgressBar color from Material to old one

Tags: android

I am using new Material design in my app. On pre-Lolipop devices ProgressBar is standard gray color and on new Lolipop devices it's greenish color. How do I force Lolipop devices to use gray color like pre-Lolipop devices use without making the new drawable for ProgressBar.

Thanks!